# Flyweight/OOP design patterns in Julia

Tags: oop, design-patterns, julia

Coming from an object oriented framework (Python) and trying to implement a Flyweight pattern in Julia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Not quite sure how to do this given the multiple dispatch framework and lack of inheritance in Julia. Wondering if any Julia experts have thought about implementations of primarily object oriented design patterns (e.g. Gang of Four) and how they can be ported over to Julia (or if not whether there are any alternatives)

Answer (score 2):

In the Julia world the best equivalent seems to be the `Memoize` package

```
using Memoize                                                                       
@memoize function x(a)                                           
    println("Computing or constructing a big data structure...")
    (a=a, b=2a)                                          
end
```

Now let us test this code

```
julia> x(7)                                                             
Computing or constructing a big data structure...
(a = 7, b = 14)                                                         

julia> x(7)                                                             
(a = 7, b = 14)
```

Note that in the second run we just got reference to the same object. Hence, no matter how many times you run `x(7)` the result will occupy the memory only once.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this in the past, I've explicitly referenced the flyweight as a constant. 
Then we explicitly define the constructor of the data structures referencing the flyweight to use the shared resource.

Using the standard Cheese Shop model from wikipedia:

```
struct CheeseSupplier
  stock::Dict{String,Float64}
  CheeseSupplier() = new(Dict())
end

stock(supplier, name, price) = supplier.stock[name] = price

const supplier = CheeseSupplier()

struct CheeseShop
  orders::Dict{String,Int64}
  supplier::CheeseSupplier
  CheeseShop() = new(Dict(), supplier)
end

totalincome(shop) = foldl((x,(k,v)) -> x + shop.supplier.stock[k]*v, shop.orders; init=0)

function sell(shop, name, amount)
  haskey(shop.supplier.stock, name) || error("Supplier doesn't have $(name)")
  shop.orders[name] = get(shop.orders, name, 0) + amount
end

shop1 = CheeseShop()
shop2 = CheeseShop()
stock(supplier, "blue", 3.75)
sell(shop1, "blue", 3)
sell(shop2, "blue", 8)
```